# Wait for a task to complete before launching an application via a batch file (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple batch file that runs just two commands (I've simplified them for clarity):

```
schtasks.exe /run /tn "FOO"
BAR.EXE
```

That's it.

Right now, if task "FOO" doesn't finish quickly, BAR.EXE is executed before "FOO" finishes.

I want to ensure task "FOO" finishes before BAR.EXE is executed.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Check to see if the process `FOO` is still running first! There are a whole host of questions and answers on this site showing how to check if a process is or is not running, please use the search facility!

Comment: @Compo The trick is that `FOO` is a task, and not a process.  It runs multiple processes, some of which may already have instances running.

Comment: You used `FOO` in the same way as I did, as a placeholder for the real information, you just meant it as a placeholder for something else. You just need to check if the process your task is running has finished running, my advice doesn't change. _You must know what process you're waiting for the completion of!_

Comment: Have you tried using `start /wait (schtasks.exe /run /tn "FOO" ^ Bar.exe ^exit)`?

Comment: Why don't you separate the two commands with && so that bar.exe will only execute after the first command has finished so in the end it will look like `schtasks.exe /run /tn "FOO" && BAR.EXE`